# MySQL query that refers to other rows

Tags: mysql, sql, date, subquery

I'm trying to make a query that takes a 'creation timestamp from one row, then COUNTs the number of unique users based on 'modification' timestamps in an INTERVAL based on the first timestamp. I get an output, but it isn't what I expect.

I have a feeling what I'm trying to do is not possible though, either because of the GROUP BY or the DATE_SUB. This is a skeleton of what I have:

```
SELECT jobid, ctime, date, foo.count

FROM Table foo

JOIN (
    SELECT
        COUNT(DISTINCT user) AS count

    FROM Table

    WHERE mtime >= DATE_SUB(ctime, INTERVAL 12 HOUR)

    GROUP BY window
) bar ON foo.id = bar.id

ORDER BY ctime
```

The purpose for this query is so that for job A, I can look at the time that job A was created, and count how many users (workers) were active in the past 12 hours based on how many have 'modified' other jobs in that interval.

So basically, with a table like this:

```
jobid    userid    ctime    mtime      date
1        Alan      9:00 AM  11:00 AM   1st
2        Bob       10:00 AM 1:00 PM    1st
3        Carla     1:00 PM  11:00 PM   2nd
4        Dave      9:00 AM  10:00 AM   3rd
5        Emma      11:00 AM 1:00 PM    3rd
```

My desired output would be this:

```
jobid    ctime      date    foo.count
2        10:00 AM   1st     1
3        1:00 PM    2nd     0
4        9:00 AM    3rd     1
5        10:00 AM   3rd     2
```

Am I on the right track with my query? Or am I wayyy off?

Edit:

```
SELECT
    ci.ctime AS "Job Creation Time",
    ci.job_id AS "Job ID",
    ci.pickup_time AS "Pickup Time",
    HOUR(wt.ctime) AS "Active Window",
    xx.Active AS "#Active in Window" 

FROM worker_to AS wt
JOIN stats_ci_data ci ON ci.job_id = wt.id
JOIN `order` o ON o.id = wt.order_id

JOIN (
    SELECT
        wt.id AS `id`, wt.ctime,
        DATE(wt.ctime) AS `date`,
        DATE_FORMAT(wt.ctime, '%m-%d-%H') AS win,
        COUNT(DISTINCT wt.worker_id) AS "Active"

        FROM worker_to wt
        JOIN `order` o ON o.id = wt.order_id

        WHERE wt.mtime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(wt.ctime, INTERVAL 12 HOUR) AND wt.ctime
        AND wt.tier != "machine"
        AND wt.preferred_worker_flag != '1'
        AND o.source LIKE '%Mozilla%'
        OR o.source LIKE 'Opera%'
        OR o.source LIKE 'Firefox%'

        GROUP BY win
    ) xx ON xx.id = wt.id

WHERE wt.tier != "machine"
AND wt.preferred_worker_flag != "1"
AND o.source LIKE '%Mozilla%'
OR o.source LIKE 'Opera%'
OR o.source LIKE 'Firefox%'

ORDER BY ci.ctime, HOUR(wt.mtime)
;
```

So, I used join instead of pulling from the same table twice because I need to put in a bunch of 'filters', like tier, preferred_worker, source. I think these are slowing down the query. But at the same time, I feel like the time interval is not giving me the right numbers either. At the moment, the subquery groups by `DATE` windows, but the numbers of active workers are like 1, 2, 3 per day, which seems really low.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure that I understand your question exactly, but I do believe you want something like this.  Do `ctime` and `mtime` contain the date and time?  If not, you'll need to replace them in the SQL below with expressions that have both date and time.  But this should at least get you started.

```
select this.jobid, this.ctime, this.date, count(*)
from   Table this, Table other
where  other.mtime between ( this.ctime - interval 12 hours ) and this.ctime
  and  this.userid != other.userid
group by this.jobid, this.ctime, this.date
```

Comment: Hey David, thanks for replying. Yes, `ctime` and `mtime`both have the date and time. I don't think the `and this.userid != ...` is what I'm looking for, but I'm trying out the `BETWEEN` operator. It doesn't seem to change the numbers I'm getting though. I think I will just post the full query tomorrow, and hopefully that will better convey what I am trying to achieve.